# EditText CurrencyFormat without symbol Android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, decimalformat

The code below produce an stackoverflow error.  The idea is to format the amount when or after user type  an amount.

500 -> 500.00

1000 -> 1 000.00

29999.55-> 29 999.55

..
..
..

```
   edit_amount.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


            if (edit_amount.getText().toString().length()>0){



                edit_amount.setText(
                        currencyFormat(edit_amount.getText().toString()));

            }else {}


        }
    });



  public String currencyFormat(String number){

        String credits="";

        try {
            //en, us

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(MyApplication.pref.GetPreferences("AppCurrency"))){

                credits = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("fr", "FR")).format(Double.valueOf(number));

            }else {

                if (MyApplication.pref.GetPreferences("AppCurrency").equals("Euro")) {

                    credits = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("fr", "FR")).format(Double.valueOf(number));

                } else {

                    credits = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("en", "US")).format(Double.valueOf(number));

                }
            }

        }catch(Exception ex){

            credits = "mCredits";

        }



        return credits;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because when you call `edit_amount.setText(...)` then the `afterTextChanged(Editable s)` is triggered and then `edit_amount.setText(...)` is triggered and so on. You need to change your logic to do what you want and avoid stack overflow.

For example you could unregister `TextWatcher`, `setText` and then register it again.

Alternatively, you can set a flag so that your `TextWatcher` knows when you change the text yourself and then instruct `TextWatcher` to ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid recursive invocation of afterTextChanged callback you can set up additional chek. Smth like this

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    if (et.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
        String src = et.getText().toString();
        String origin = currencyFormat(src);
        if(!src.equals(origin)) {
            et.setText(currencyFormat(et.getText().toString()));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
private String current = "";
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    if(!s.toString().equals(current)){
       [your_edittext].removeTextChangedListener(this);

       String cleanString = s.toString().replaceAll("[$,.]", "");

       double parsed = Double.parseDouble(cleanString);
       String formatted = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format((parsed/100));

       current = formatted;
       [your_edittext].setText(formatted);
       [your_edittext].setSelection(formatted.length());

       [your_edittext].addTextChangedListener(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: error message java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "000 €8"

Comment: The reason is, that "" is not a valid double. You need to test the String before or catch such exceptions

Comment: If this answer helps you or solved your problem then please accept it as answer and upvote it.

Comment: use this for replacing ("\\P{L}", " ")

Comment: nothing happens anyway thanks i will find an alternative